# How to find lines including two letter words using grep

Tags: unix, grep

I'd like to find lines that include two character words in a text file.

I've tried:

```
grep '..' file.txt
grep '[..]' file.txt
grep -w '..' file.txt
grep -w '[..]' file.txt
egrep '(\b^[.]|[.]$)' file.txt
egrep '(\b^[.]|[.]$|[..])' file.txt
egrep '..|[..]' file.txt
```

but it does not catch all the lines needed.

Any ideas?

Comment: `This may become it.` and  `Why me?` should this give true as a two letter word for `it` and `me?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "word mode":

```
$ cat file.txt
A AB CDE
ABD KJSD
SD DAD LD

$ grep -w '..' file.txt 
A AB CDE
SD DAD LD
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole
          words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
          Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
          underscore.
```

The problem with your attempts is that you use a *character class* (denoted by square brackets). So your regex is kind of redundant matches only literal dots. If you remove the square brackets, it will match any combination of two characters, which seems to be what you intended, but that will not be a correct solution, because `.` will match non-word characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some `awk` versions.

```
awk '{f=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (length($i)==2) f=1}f' file
```

If any fields in the line is `2` characters, set flag  `f`.
If flag `f` is true, print the line.

---

```
awk 'gsub(/(^|[ \t])..([ \t\.\?]|$)/,"&")' file
```

This try to change the text if its only two characters
in start of line follow by space or tabs, ends with space/tabs/./ or end of line.

This also works with lines like:

```
This may become it.
```

Test of field length will fail on this line and does not see `it.` as a two character word.

Comment: Just noting, the `grep` command from my answer does not fail on your last example.